# Java in Android Studio: Weirdness when writing value into array of user defined class

Tags: java, arrays, class, subscript

I am writing my first app in Android Studio, I am a self-taught novice.  When I write data into the subscript of an array I have created as a user-defined class the value is written into an adjacent subscript as well!  Have traced to some code where I move data down one position in the array, thought I could do this in one operation, but it seems this messes something up and I need to copy each member of the class individually.

Here is my class

```
class LeaderboardClass
{
    public String DateTime;
    public String UserName;
    public long Milliseconds; //0 denotes not in use
}
```

Here is my array declaration

```
LeaderboardClass[] LeaderboardData = new LeaderboardClass[LeaderboardEntries];
```

I want to move some data from subscript j to subscript j+1

I tried

```
LeaderboardData[j + 1] = LeaderboardData[j];
```

I thought this would copy all the data from subscript j to j+1

Then when I subsequently write to the array I (subscript i) I get the correct entry I made, plus a duplicate entry in the adjacent subscript i+1.

When I rewrite the above to:

```
            LeaderboardData[j + 1].UserName = LeaderboardData[j].UserName;
            LeaderboardData[j + 1].DateTime = LeaderboardData[j].DateTime;
            LeaderboardData[j + 1].Milliseconds = LeaderboardData[j].Milliseconds;
```

Everything else behaves as expected.  So I was wondering exactly what is happening with my first (presumably incorrect) code?

Thanks.

Comment: both the `j` and `j+1` indices hold a reference to the same object

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there's a difference between primitive values and objects (instances of classes): Primitives are stored by value whereas objects are stored by reference. This means that your code would work as you expect if you were using integers. However, since you are using a class, the array merely stores the references to those objects. Hence, when you do `LeaderboardData[j + 1] = LeaderboardData[j];` you are merely copying the reference of that object. Therefore, `LeaderboardData[j + 1]`and `LeaderboardData[j]` will point to the same object.

**Sidenote:** If you run your program with a debugger, you can actually see this in action:

[image]

The number behind the `@` denotes the reference number and if you look closely, you can see that the objects at indices 8 and 9 both have the reference `@716`.

**To fix this,** I would suggest that you use lists instead of arrays as they allow you to remove and add new entries. The standard list implementation is an `ArrayList` but in your use-case, a `LinkedList` might be more efficient.

Lastly, a closing notes on your code: For variable names (like `DateTime`, `UserName` or `LeaderboardData` should always start with a lowercase letter to distinguish them from classes. That way, you can avoid lots of confusion - especially because Java also has a built-in class called `DateTime`.